# Calling a function from another JS file And Node Directory Structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-structure

`MessageHandler.HandleMessage(message);`The question might seem to be 2 parts, but I think there might be overlap between them.

I'm making a very simple Node application where I could, theoretically, put all my functions in the same JS file. However like C# (where you could theoretically put all your classes on the same page) this is going to get cluttered very quickly and is likely considered bad practice.

I have the basic node generation structure (as shown in the sublime explorer):

[image]

But I'm not sure where is the *standard* place for me to start putting my JS.

Looping back to the first part of my question I have this very simple code.

```
    //file: MyNode.js
    const MessageHandler = require('MessageHandler.js');
    var message = "Hello world!";
    MessageHandler.HandleMessage(message);
```

And:

```
    //file: MessageHandler.js
    function HandleMessage(message)
    {
        Console.log('Message is this: ' + message);

    }
```

They are in the same file directory but during execution I get a `HandleMessage is not a function.` type error. Is there a structuring or scope problem that I'm not seeing?

Comment: you have to add something like `module.exports = HandleMessage;` (look up the exact syntax) to the MessageHandler.js file. As written, you are not exporting that function, so you can't `require()` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your code is correct but needs little addition, you need to export the required function to expose or to use in another js file.

```
// a.js
anyFun() {
// body
}

you can use module.exports = anyFun;

//b.js

let a = require('./a')

a(); 

    In your case:

    //file: MessageHandler.js
       module.exports.HandleMessage = function HandleMessage(message)
    {
        console.log('Message is this: ' + message);

    }

   //file: MyNode.js

  let demo = require("./MessageHandler");

  demo.HandleMessage('hello');
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I'm afraid that fix isn't working for me - same error. I'm looking into `module.exports` now though.

Comment: use the relative path in require('./MessageHandler') , .js is not required tho! :)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I am using the relative path since I saw your answer. The issue is still persisting - but thanks!

Comment: Hi @James, I have updated the answer, please copy paste and let me know any issue.

Comment: You have made console.log ''C" capital in MessageHandler.js file, correct it.

Comment: Was just writing to say that the capital C was a problem.! Other than that it's worked correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! :)